Git pull error: fatal: expected 'acknowledgments'
We are using Github to host our repo and the authentication mechanism is through an app.
The git pull randomly fails with the following error.   Emphasis on "randomly", it works 90% of the time but we keep seeing this error randomly.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401
fatal: expected 'acknowledgments'

Q: Any idea what can cause this?

HTTP 401 is "authentication required" - either you've provided invalid credentials, or you've provided no credentials at all.

There was a fix in git version 2.8 related to RPC.
